# differential equation of a population growth and change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I want to formulate a system of equations and initial conditions of the following data:
Each year the population1 grows by 4% and population2 by 2%.
Also each year 3% of population1 leaves it and go to population2
and 1% vice versa, leaves population2 and goes to population1.

The initial populations are: population1 = 20000000, population2 = 5000000.

I thought of the next formalism of this:
$$x(t+1)=1.04*x(t)-0.03*x(t)+0.01*y(t)$$
$$y(t+1)=1.02*y(t)-0.01*y(t)+0.03*x(t)$$

where $x(t)$ is the size of population1 and $y(t)$ is the size of population2.
Is this is correct in those term or maybe I should reformulate it in another way ?

I think that I need some how to get something like this (ignore the concrete number and function):
$$\overline{X'}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-2 & -2\end{pmatrix}\overline{X}+\begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}\\-2e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

with an initial conditions like that:
$$\overline{X}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

but I don't know how to do it, so will be grateful for some help.

An idea I had is:
$$x'\left(t\right)=\frac{x\left(t+1\right)−x\left(t\right)}{\left(t+1−t\right)}=\left(1.04−0.03−1\right)x\left(t\right)+0.01y\left(t\right)$$

is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For population  denoted by $x$, you get $$x'=.04x-.03x+.01y$$ and for the second population denoted by $y$ you get $$ y'=.02y+.03x-.01y$$

That simplifies to $$x'=.01x+.01y$$ and $$y'=.03x+.01y$$

Now you write it in matrix form.

Comment: Is the reason it is correct is: $x'\left(t\right)=\frac{x\left(t+1\right)-x\left(t\right)}{t+1-t}=\left(1.04\:-0.03-1\right)x\left(t\right)+0.01y\left(t\right)$  ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of ambiguity in the way things are stated, but it seems you have something like this in mind.

For a year you're modeling the
overall change in the first population, $x(t + 1) - x(t)$, as being the result of:

- Some sort of inherent growth, adding $0.04 \times x(t)$.
- A loss to population 2, removing $0.03\times x(t)$.
- New additions coming from population 2, adding $0.01 \times y(t)$.

That gives you
\begin{equation}
x(t + 1) - x(t) = (0.04 - 0.03)\,x(t) + 0.01\,y(t).
\end{equation}

Same sort of thing for population 2:
\begin{equation}
y(t + 1) - y(t) = 0.03\,x(t) + (0.02 - 0.01 )\,y(t).
\end{equation}
Maybe easier to write
\begin{align}
x(t + \Delta t) - x(t)) &= (A\Delta t)x(t) + (B\Delta t)y(t) \\
y(t + \Delta t) - y(t)) &= (C\Delta t)x(t) + (D\Delta t)y(t)
\end{align}
where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are rates since it looks like you might have an eye on shifting to a continuous model ($\Delta t \rightarrow 0$). In that case you get the system
\begin{align}
x'(t) &= A x(t) + B y(t) \\
y'(t) &= C x(t) + D y(t),
\end{align}
and typically you'd have initial conditions.

But, if that's not what you're after, the original problem would end up looking like
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t + 1)\\
y(t + 1)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.01 & 0.01 \\
0.03 & 0.01
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t)
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
and if you're working from initial conditions you end up with
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(n)\\
y(n)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.01 & 0.01 \\
0.03 & 0.01
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
x(0) \\
y(0)
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Comment: can you maybe explain why it isn't just what the previous answerer wrote ? 
Like why is the difference with x(n) and x(t) ? 
And compare your answer to the previous one ?
Because if it was up to me, my logic also says:
$$x'=.01x+.01y$$ 
 $$y'=.03x+.01y$$
because:
$$x'\left(t\right)=\frac{x\left(t+1\right)−x\left(t\right)}{\left(t+1−t\right)}=\left(1.04−0.03−1\right)x\left(t\right)+0.01y\left(t\right)$$

Comment: If you're defining $x'$ as the annual difference in $x$, then yep you're right. Lots of folks use $x'$, $y'$ to indicate a derivative, but to each his or her own I suppose.